# Android: how to reuse my listview layout depending on the transaction of user for previewing its transaction

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, transactions

This is the whole xml file format I want to reuse for print preview of the user to be transact depending how many payment type the user to be process. is there a technique like copying this whole layout and to be added below of the first list. and bounding the data per list..

```
<RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/relativeModeOfPaymentCheck"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/relativeModeOfPayment"
              android:background="#000000" >

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearForCheck"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"

          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="5dp" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewModeOfPaymentCheckValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Mode of Payment Value check"

              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />        
     </LinearLayout>
          <!-- asdasda -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearForAmountModeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearCheckDate"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="2" >

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:id="@+id/relativeBlock100"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000" >

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textViewModAmountCheck"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="AMOUNT"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff" />
              </RelativeLayout>

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:id="@+id/relativeBlock101"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000" >

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textViewModeOfPayCheckValue"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="100.00"
                      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff" />
              </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
          <!-- name of check issued -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearForNameCheckIssued"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearForCheck"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="2" >

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:id="@+id/relativeBlock101"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000" >

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textViewBankNameCheckIssued"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="RIZAL COMMERCIAL BANKING CORP."
                      android:textColor="#ffffff" />
              </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>


          <!-- CHECK NUMBER -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearCheckNumber"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearForNameCheckIssued"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckNumber"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:text="CHECK # : "
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckNumValue"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="3464646464"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />
          </LinearLayout>
         <!-- CHECK DATE -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearCheckDate"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearCheckNumber"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckDate"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:text="CHECK DATE : "
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckDateValue"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="08/02/2013"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />
          </LinearLayout> 


        <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearLineForCheck"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="2dp"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearForAmountModeOfPayment"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

                  <View
                      android:id="@+id/View201"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:background="#ffffff" />
          </LinearLayout>  


          </RelativeLayout>
```

I'm also implementing that hide/unhide of the parent layout... but it will be limited to an single process per type.. here is my scenario.. I have 5 payment type the one I've given is for the preview of check.. each payment type can have multiple transaction and its ID number, payment is unique but same type.. like when the user uses to pay 3 checks but from different bank the ID is different and it's bank name and the amount to be transact.. that's why I want to re-use my layout because the data can be bound to an assigned labels..

Comment: You can manage it by hide/unhide your layout as per your needs. As your question is not more clear can not provide exact solution.

Comment: i edited my post so you could understand my point.. thanks

Comment: is it possible to use with an adapter...?